# Trigger change on input when jQuery datepicker date selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, datepicker

I am working on a web application and trying to change class on change to that input box. Almost all the input box are working well instead of them in which I have used datepicker.

The problem what I am facing is, when I select a date from that datepicker values shows inside that input but it doesn't trigger the 'CHANGE' on that input. I have done 'onChange' event by doing this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input').on("change", function() {
       if($(this).val() != ''){
           $(this).parent().addClass("filled");
       }
    });
});
```

This is working fine but not with datepicker. I have found number of questions related to 'onSelect' of datepicker but I don't wanna do that for a single one.
like this..

```
$('.custom_datepicker_selector').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(en{});
```

or

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {}
});
```

These are just updating for single one and my problem is to make it global for all. I want to do like I will not need to change every single datepicker initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onSelect` event of datepicker to detect when input value change, Try:

```
$("#dp").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("filled");
    }
});
```

example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dp").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("filled");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="dp">
</div>
```